Use VSCode to debug Windows Script Host scripts
Is there a way to configure VSCode to allow me to debug old JavaScript (JScript?) or VBScript routines that run in the Windows Script Host?  I'd like to step through the code of each of these scripts to inspect variable values and types at various points.
